# NullReferenceException While Populating an Array

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonField
{
    private string _fieldName;
    private object _fieldValue;

    public PersonField()
    {
    }

    public PersonField(string FieldName, object FieldValue)
    {
        _fieldName = FieldName;
        _fieldValue = FieldValue;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _fieldName; }
        set { _fieldName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public object FieldValue
    {
        get { return _fieldValue; }
        set { _fieldValue = value; }
    }
}
```

I have this class above which is used in my WCF service.
when i try to create array on client side for this like

```
PersonField[] test = new PersonField[2];
test[0].FieldName = "test";
```

i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. not sure what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Try `PersonField[] test = new PersonField[2]; test[0] = new PersonField(); test[0].FieldName = "test";` This has nothing at all to do with serialization.

Comment: Why the downvote? Its a simple answer, but I see nothing wrong with the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to do this. Yo need to initialize `test[0]` with `new` keyword as well.

```
PersonField[] test = new PersonField[2];
test[0] = new  PersonField();
test[0].FieldName = "test";
test[1] = new  PersonField();
test[1].FieldName = "test2";
```

> **Value Type and Reference Type Arrays**
>
> Consider the following array declaration: C#
>
> **SomeType[] array4 = new SomeType[10];**
>
> The result of this statement depends on whether SomeType is a value
>   type or a reference type. If it is a value type, the statement results
>   in creating an array of 10 instances of the type SomeType. If SomeType
>   is a reference type, the statement creates an array of 10 elements,
>   each of which is initialized to a null reference.
>
> For more information on value types and reference types, see Types (C#
>   Reference).

[Here is MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a class, you're creating an array of references, not the actual objects.  You still need to allocate the instance(s) yourself:

```
PersonField[] test = new PersonField[2];
test[0] = new PersonField();
test[0].FieldName = "test";
test[1] = new PersonField();
```